# Asus A450LC BIOS Can't detect any harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, sata, hardware-detection

my laptop suddenly rebooted when i was used it for browsing with chrome. After reboot BIOS says that no bootable device are detected, then i check out my BIOS config then it appear my HDD not detected by the BIOS i also doesn't hear any harddrive sound like before. What happen with my laptop and what should i do to fix this problem.

[Screenshoot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNWTG.jpg)

[Screenshoot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrBpq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not detect the normal sound of an HDD spinning and the computer no longer detects it then either of these have gone wrong:

1. Your HDD dried. Period. Validate this by removing the drive and trying it in another computer or in an external eSATA/USB-to-SATA/firewire-to SATA/etc etc caddy.
2. Or the power to the drive failed because the connector came loose. Unlikely in a laptop, but possible. A simple reseating of the drive should help.
3. Or the power supply to the drive fails on the laptops motherboard. Which would be bad news but is rather unlikely.

In your case, I would:

- Power down the laptop.
- disconnected external power.
- Press the power button a few seconds.
- Try again (the previous sort of resets things).
- If failed remove the drive and plug it back in. Try again.
- If that still fails connect it elsewhere. Luckily SATA is a standard format and you should be able to plug in as an additional drive in a average desktop. If it still does not work there then the drive is dead. Get a new drive (HDD or SSD), reinstall the OS and restore your data from backups.